# Pass some parameter to adfs server and get the same parameter when login is successful in response?

Tags: saml-2.0, adfs3.0

My request URL look like this

https://adfs.plugins.local/adfs/ls?SAMLRequest=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&adfs_server=597fb898d8aaa44338fc43ff&RelayState=https://192.168.4.206/pluggables/Authentication/ADFSAuthentication/authenticate

I have passed a parameter called **adfs_server** but when I got the response the **adfs_server** parameter was not present.

So is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is SAML.

There is no parameter in the SAML protocol called "adfs_server" so it is ignored.